# Print '*' trapezium in java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I am looking to create an asterisk trapezium in Java like the pattern below using nested for-loop.

```
**
****
********
```

I know how to print like two, four then six asterisks, like in the code below. However, I don't know how to create two, four, then eight.

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<=(i*2); j++) {
        System.out.print('*');
    }            
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I think considering it's 2-4-8 which is 2^1, 2^2, 2^3 you should probably use Math.pow() or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing i*2 asterisks in the inner loop, print Math.pow(2,i) asterisks (i.e. 2^i).

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<=Math.pow(2,i); j++) {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```